# How can I get the vertical profile of my trail?

Tags: profile

I am creating some online maps for trails and I'm trying to figure out how to turn my lat/long data into vertical profiles roughly like the following.  I'm not so concerned about the markers/labels, though the x/y axes would be nice to have.

[image]

So far I have just been building out a prototype using Leaflet.js - soon I expect to do a full overhaul, possibly using Drupal as a framework/CMS.  So the door is wide open as far as implementation goes - it would just need to be something I can do programatically from a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MapQuest** has an [Elevation Service API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/elevation-service) you can use (for free).

All you need is an [API Key](http://developer.mapquest.com/).

I recommend creating your own graph as their default one is not very aesthetically pleasing.